# CefSharp browser isn't firing any Mouse-Events in C# WinForms app

Tags: c#, winforms, handler, cefsharp, mousedown

So my end goal is to detect when the user has pressed the left mouse button on a webpage (any element like a button, image and so on).
With this I'd run some javascript to get the proper html data I need based on where the user has clicked.

Without taking it any further, I'm already stuck at the first part where my browser control doesn't seem to fire any events related to the mouse. However it does seem to provide handlers like MouseDown, MouseEnter, MouseClick and so on but doesn't seem to fire any of them.

I've tried setting up a simple WinForms test project with a textbox control and a button. The browser is added manually like so:

```cs
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace myProject
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
        private string myUrl = "https://www.google.com/";
        
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeChromium();

            browser.MouseDown += ChromeBrowser_MouseDown;
        }

        public void InitializeChromium()
        {
            browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(myUrl);

            browser.Location = new Point(26, 59);
            browser.Size = new Size(988,566);
            browser.Dock = DockStyle.None;
            this.Controls.Add(browser);

        }

        private void ChromeBrowser_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //This handler never gets fired!!!

            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                //get value from html element
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            browser.Load(addressBar.Text);
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Cef.Shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried looking through a bunch of websites including the official [Documentation on Handlers](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#handlers), but can't seem to figure out if I have to do more complex stuff to listen and act on mouse events or that I should be able to implement it just like any other event.

Can anybody help me fix my MouseDown event handler?

Comment: This is expected, neither mouse or keyboard events will fire. For your use case I'd suggest you look at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#JSEvent

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up @amaitland! Also, the link was very helpful and did exactly what I was looking for regarding the handling of Mouse events! 
I'll post my own answer later when I get the chance to mark all of this as "Solved". Once again thanks for helping!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It took a while, but finally got around to posting my own answer! Hopefully others will find this useful.

Thanks to @amaitland for pointing out in the comments that CefSharp browser will not fire any keyboard or Mouse events and also for posting [this link](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#JSEvent) which ultimately led me to my answer.

The workaround is to inject some Javascript (when the browser is done loading a frame) which will then listen to & detect any mouse/keyboard events. Upon fire, your Javascript then calls `CefSharp.PostMessage(data);` which notifies the CefSharp browser on its own thread and returns any useful `data` (depending on your script).

### Initializing Event Handlers

Adding `browser.JavascriptMessageReceived += Browser_JavascriptMessageReceived;` & `browser.FrameLoadEnd += Browser_FrameLoadEnd;` to your initialization will activate the necessary hooks, like so (following my original example):

```cs
public void InitializeChromium()
        {
            browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(myUrl);

            browser.Location = new Point(26, 59);
            browser.Size = new Size(988,566);
            browser.Dock = DockStyle.None;
            this.Controls.Add(browser);

            browser.JavascriptMessageReceived += Browser_JavascriptMessageReceived;
            browser.FrameLoadEnd += Browser_FrameLoadEnd;
        }
```

### Implementing Event Handlers

Now all that's left to do is to implement these event handlers by adding the following:

```cs
        private void Browser_FrameLoadEnd(object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Frame.IsMain)
            {
                browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(@"
                    document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                        var parent = e.target.parentElement;

                        // run some validation with if(){..}
                        // some more javascript

                        CefSharp.PostMessage(parent.outerHTML);
                    }, false);
                ");
            }
        }

        private void Browser_JavascriptMessageReceived(object sender, JavascriptMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Message != null)
            {
                // Extract data from e.Message.toString() and use delegates/callbacks/Invokes 
                // to reference the main UI thread for updating the necessary controls.
            }
        }
```

Once the webpage/frame is loaded, the `Browser_FrameLoadEnd` handler will run which will then inject your custom Javascript.
The `Browser_JavascriptMessageReceived` handler will only be fired when `CefSharp.PostMessage(data);` is called from your Javascript.

Also, instead of using `document.body.onmouseup` in the javascript as suggested by [this link](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#JSEvent), I opted to go for `document.addEventListener('click', function(e)` in order to get the targeted/clicked element along with it. In my case this was crucial in order to get the necessary data which belonged to the parentElement of this clicked element. (*keep in mind that my actual case is meant for a different website than google as suggested by my example*)

## Full Example Code

The full extended example code would look something like this:

```cs
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace myProject
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
        private string myUrl = "https://www.google.com/";
        
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeChromium();
        }

        public void InitializeChromium()
        {
            browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(myUrl);

            browser.Location = new Point(26, 59);
            browser.Size = new Size(988,566);
            browser.Dock = DockStyle.None;
            this.Controls.Add(browser);

            browser.JavascriptMessageReceived += Browser_JavascriptMessageReceived;
            browser.FrameLoadEnd += Browser_FrameLoadEnd;
        }

        private void Browser_FrameLoadEnd(object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Frame.IsMain)
            {
                browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(@"
                    document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                        var parent = e.target.parentElement;

                        // run some validation with if(){..}
                        // some more javascript

                        CefSharp.PostMessage(parent.outerHTML);
                    }, false);
                ");
            }
        }

        private void Browser_JavascriptMessageReceived(object sender, JavascriptMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Message != null)
            {
                // Extract data from e.Message.toString() and use delegates/callbacks/Invokes 
                // to reference the main UI thread for updating the necessary controls.
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            browser.Load(addressBar.Text);
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Cef.Shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```